# Javascript: How to check if button's click function is assigned

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, onclick

I know this question has been asked, but this is **different from that question**.  I am trying to solve it with mere **Javascript**.

The problem relates to my **backbone.js** application, which I've brought down to the simplest form, yet can't get **events** to work.  Any suggestion would be most appreciated.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning About Backbone.js Views</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container { padding:20px; border:1px solid #333; width:400px; }
        #list-template { display:none; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var ListView=Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('initialized');
        },
        el:'body',
        events:{
            'click #add':'time',
            'click':'whatApp'
        },
        time: function()
        {
            console.log('hooooooop');
        },
        whatApp:function()
        {
            console.log('Coool');
        }
      });
      var listView = new ListView();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='add'>Add list item</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: Your code works here: (jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/RrP9a/

Comment: Lol, how cannot work in my computer. I'm using a MAMP server and inspecting everything from Chrome's console.

Comment: Try moving your JavaScript to the bottom of the page. It shouldn't help, since Backbone uses event delegation, but try just to make sure. It is the only difference I can find, comparing it to my jsfiddle. (they wrap JS in a `window.load` callback function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with what you are doing.
You are trying to initialize the view before the body (or the dom) is there.
You should initialize the view **after** the dom is loaded:

```
$(function(){
  var listView = new ListView();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you should be able to use the Data API to view events and assigned functions:

```
$('#add').data('events')
```

Comment: OP explicitly states that this is to be solved with plain JavaScript.

Comment: Oh boy. Didn't notice that. He did include jQuery in the above code, though. Why not use it then?